# Launch Explorer window on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, explorer

Okay scratch that - I had to run it as Admin to launch an explorer window. Why is that? How do I allow it to be launched as a non admin? Is it because of my system?

Comment: temporarily you can do a check for isDesktopSupported() throw unsupported exception and wait till support is there for windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 8 and Java 6 and it is working fine.

Can you let us know more detail like java version etc. or error you are getting ?

Are you able to compile the code ?

Comment: I edited my question. The problem was I had to run it as an admin